# Django takes ubuntu username to connect database instead of db user from settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I trying to run django website on aws ec2 machine (ubuntu). my postgresql database running on aws RDS

when I run $python manage.py runserver, it throws this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxxxx.xxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (xxx.xx.xx.xxx), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
```

basically django trying to connect database using ubuntu user instead of postgres user in settings.py

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': config('NAME'),
    'USER': config('USER'),
    'PASSWORD':config('PASSWORD'),
    'HOST':config('HOST')
    #'HOST':'localhost'
}
```

}

.env file:

```
SECRET_KEY=xxxx
DEBUG=True
HOST=xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
NAME=xxxx
USER=postgres
PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```

my password has special special char '#'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Linux distribution typically uses the `$USER` variable to specify the name of the user, not of the database.

I would advise to use `$DB_USER` or something similar, so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD':config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST':config('DB_HOST')
    }
}
```

and then configure with:

```
SECRET_KEY=xxxx
DEBUG=True
DB_HOST=xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_NAME=xxxx
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```